# Upgraded my app to Windows Phone 8.1. Still no PlaceholderText on TextBox/PasswordBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

So i needed some placeholder text on a PasswordBox for my Windows Phone app. My app was created as a Windows Phone 8.0 project. Then came the 8.1 update and i found out that it contained a property on TextBox's and PasswordBox's named `PlaceholderText`. So i upgraded to 8.1 by right clicking my project and press "retarget for windows phone 8.1", after that i checked for updates to NuGet packets(There was non).

Thing is that my .xaml doc still can't find that property `PlaceholderText`. So what could i be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2014/04/whats-new-for-wp8dev-textbox.html) thread `Placeholdertext` is only applicable for WP 8.1 Universal (RunTime) apps.

Make sure that yours is not a WP Silverlight app.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Well thanks that helps a lot:) It is a WP 8.1 silverlight app. But i didn't have a option to make it a WP 8.1 Universal app. I followed this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642081(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Yeah that's somewhat unfortunate. Maybe it could be available in the future.